# Magento: Set up multiple domain error

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, ce-1.9.0.1

I create a New Store in Magento with the code **myshop** and I add a domain in cPanel with the name **my-shop.com**, after I setup everything i copy the index.php file and .htaccess in the root my-shop.com, in index.php i add this:

```
$mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';
```

and this

```
Mage::run('myshop', 'website');
```

but when i try to access the new domain my-shop.com i get this error "NetworkError: 404 Not Found". Anyone can tell me what is wrong?

I will list my errors:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://my-shop.com/"
my-shop.com
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://my-shop.com/skin/frontend/default/theme668/css/styles.css"
styles.css
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://my-shop.com/skin/frontend/default/theme668/css/photoswipe.css"
photoswipe.css
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://my-shop.com/js/calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css"
calenda...k-1.css
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://my-shop.com/skin/frontend/default/theme668/css/jquery.bxslider.css"
jquery....der.css
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://my-shop.com/skin/frontend/default/theme668/css/bootstrap.css"
bootstrap.css
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://my-shop.com/skin/frontend/default/theme668/css/font-awesome.css"
font-awesome.css
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://my-shop.com/skin/frontend/default/theme668/css/responsive.css"
```

Comment: why you need to copy files into different place? cant you just point everything to the same IP and root folder and use magento shop code in htaccess as an Env variable?

Comment: i don;t need to copy in different place, i just use the addon domain in cPanel, this function add a folder in the root with the name of your new website, in my root of my new website exist only symbolic links. The domain have the same IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add new folder ie myshop.
if you are using add domain method. Then add these two files ie index.php and .htaccess file. and  do the process same